# IEnvironment.StackTrace using Visual Studio extension c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, callstack, visual-studio-extensions

Environment.StackTrace is useful in obtaining stackTrace of currently running application. Can we leverage this for building visual studio extensions.

For Ex.

- Have created small visual studio extension "ABC"
- Extension is been installed
- Open a web application
- Run the given extension "ABC" for web application

I need to obtain call stack of the running web application. Is this possible using Visual studio Extensions. If so?? how do I achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EnvDTE.Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.debugger.aspx) property to get the debugger information. From there you can get a thread or threads and then get stack traces from it. To get to the EnvDTE object, you can follow the directions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw.aspx), although the steps vary slightly depending upon how you are registering your extension. I'm pretty sure I've answered questions on that before around here, so just search and you'll find some hits.